# how to read and get the first line followed by the string "published" .net

Tags: .net, string

i want to get the next first line followed by the string "published". here is my code:

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
Dim reader As New StringReader(txtOCR.Text)
While True
    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
    If line Is Nothing Then Exit While
    If Not line.ToLower().Contains("published") Then
        builder.AppendLine(line)
    End If
End While
txtOCR.Text = builder.ToString()
```

this code gets all the lines followed by the string "published" but i only want to get the next first line..

Comment: It's unclear whether you want the first line *after* the word "published" is found, or the line that comes immediately *before* the word "published" is found. Or do you want the first line that contains the word "published"?

Comment: i want the line found after the word "published" sir..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the line that comes after the line that contains the word "published":

```
Dim found as Boolean = False
Dim line as String = reader.ReadLine()
While Not line is Nothing
    If Found Then
        builder.AppendLine(line)
        Exit While
    End If
    If line.ToLower().Contains("published") Then
        Found = True
    End If
    line = reader.ReadLine()
End While
```

Please excuse any syntax errors. I'm not real fluent in VB.